# Can MailPoet be made to work with Postman SMTP or Gmail API?

Tags: wordpress, email, gmail-api, swiftmailer

I would like to use MailPoet 3 to send my site updates to subscribers, however there is no built-in way for MailPoet to use `wp_mail()`, Postman SMTP or Gmail API for sending. (That I can find)

Has anyone gotten these components to work together? Seems viable could be:

```
1. MailPoet -> SwiftMailer -> Gmail API transport
2. MailPoet -> SwiftMailer -> wp_mail() -> Postman SMTP
3. MailPoet -> SwiftMailer -> Postman SMTP
```

I'm willing to write a SwiftMailer transport and change the MailPoet plugin to do what I want but really hoping for existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an old question but there's also an old answer: https://cfxdesign.com/email-wordpress-posts-to-subscribers-with-mandrill-and-mailpoet/

I haven't yet tested it out but this was their solution, add this to the functions.php file

```
function mailpoet_enable_wpmail(){
  if(class_exists('WYSIJA')){
    $model_config = WYSIJA::get('config','model');
    $model_config->save(array('allow_wpmail' => true));
  }
}
add_action('init', 'mailpoet_enable_wpmail');
```